# Botón hamburguesa no se alinea a la derecha y solo al centro en blogger

Tags: css, html5, xml, botón, blogger

buenas noches

Estoy tratando de elaborar una plantilla para blogger, el código lo pude desarrollar bien en Visual Studio Code y funciona bien, no hay ningun problema, pero al pasarlo a blogger me encontré con el inconveniente de que el botón hamburguesa no se alinea a la derecha. Cabe mencionar que de xml no se absolutamente nada, pero me anime a hacer esto ya que la sintaxis  de blogger se pueden hacer algunas cosas con html, css y javascript, por eso es mi interes,  por ahora solo estoy maquetando y me encontré con esta traba. Por favor ¿me podría alguien sacar de mi error?

La base del código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  <head>
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
    <b:skin><![CDATA[
```

CSS:

```
  /* Estilos generales */

    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

      body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
background: #deded2;
        
      }

      .nav {
          background: #293241;
          height: 80px;
          color:#fff;
      }


      .nav_container {
          display: flex;
          height: 100%;
          width: 90%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items: center;
      }

      .nav_input:checked + .nav_menu {
         background: tomato;
      }

      .nav_logo {
          font-size: 1.5em;
          font-weight: 900;
      }

      .nav_menu {
          display: grid;
          grid-auto-flow: column;
          gap: 3em;

      }

      .nav_item {
          color: #fff;
          text-decoration: none;
          --clippy: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0% 100%);

      }

      .nav_item::after{
          content: "";
          display: block;
          background: #c72828;
          width: 90%;
          margin-top: 3px;
          height: 3px;
          clip-path: var(--clippy);
          transition: clip-path .3s;
      }

      .nav_item:hover {
          --clippy: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%); 
      }

      .nav_label, .nav_input {
          display: none;
cursor:pointer;
      }


/* Estilos de los elementos del menú */

      main {
        padding: 20px;
      }

      footer {
        background-color: #333;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 0;
      }

      /* Estilos para hacer la plantilla responsive */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
       .nav_label {
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 40px;
justify-content: flex-end; /* Alinea el botón a la derecha */
  padding-right: 20px;
       }
   
    .nav_menu {
        position: fixed;
        top: 80px;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #f09090;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        clip-path: circle(0 at center);
        transition: clip-path 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    }

    .nav_input:checked + .nav_menu {
        clip-path: circle(100% at center);
    }
    ]]></b:skin>
  </head>
```

HTML:

```
  <body>
      <b:section class='main' id='main' showaddelement='yes'/>
 
        <nav class='nav'> 
        <div class='nav_container'> 
           <h1 class='nav_logo'>Prueba</h1>
         <label class='nav_label' for='menu'>&#9776;</label>
        <img alt='' class='nav_img' src='/assets/menu.svg'/>
            <input class='nav_input' id='menu' type='checkbox'/>
           <div class='nav_menu'>     
           <a class='nav_item' href='https://corsomexico.blogspot.com/'>Inicio</a>
                 <a class='nav_item' href='https://corsomexico.blogspot.com/p/aprender.html'>Aprender</a>
                 <a class='nav_item' href='https://corsomexico.blogspot.com/p/mundiales.html'>Mundiales</a>
                <a class='nav_item' href='https://corsomexico.blogspot.com/p/tienda.html'>Tienda</a>
                <a class='nav_item' href='https://corsomexico.blogspot.com/p/contacto.html'>Contacto</a>
           </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
  
      <main>
        <!-- Contenido principal del blog -->
        <article>
          <h2> Prueba</h2>
          <p>Contenido de la entrada</p>
        </article>
        <!-- Más entradas -->
      </main>

      <footer>
        <!-- Pie de página -->
        <p>Pie de página</p>
      </footer>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

El enlace de prueba es el siguiente: [Blog de pruebas](https://corsomexico.blogspot.com)

De antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda,

Saludos a todos

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, solo tenía que borrar la línea de código:

```
<img alt='' class='nav_img' src='/assets/menu.svg'/>
```

De igual manera, muchas gracias por que leyeron esto

Saludos :)